# Handling combo boxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I've some comboboxes and need the values of selected comboboxes.

Im doing this:

But is not working.

```
var check_combo_box_values = $('#combos .combo').filter(function() { 
                return this.selectedIndex === 0;
                }).map(function () 
                {
                    return $('option:selected', this).map(function() {
                    return parseInt(this.value);
                    }).get();
                }).get();
```

By the other hand, this is working:

```
var combo_box_values = $('#combos .combo').filter(function() {
                return this.selectedIndex === 0;
                }).map(function () 
                {
                    return $('option:not(:selected)', this).map(function() {
                    return parseInt(this.value);
                    }).get();
                }).get();
```

I had the second code, and tried to adapt it to my needs and the 1st try appeared. Seems not correct (: Where is the error?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `.filter()` this method filters the results from your first selection `$('#combos .combo')`. So from your filter you're only receiving the comboboxes that have their first option selected. If you wish to get all selected values of all comboboxes you need to remove the filter **or** reverse the filter in case you don't want those that have their first element selected (which is mostly a default element)

If you just generally wish all selected options you can just use this: http://jsfiddle.net/nqTNH/